# cells are weighted to the right instead of the left

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

In the first tab of the sample program: In the first row the components are r and l justified in their cells. In the second row the cell is spanned and pushed to the right.

All of the excess space in the first row is given to cell 0,0 which contains the component labelled "20".

Tab "Two" improves the situation by using pushx. The widget looked centered but that is not what I want.

But how do I give all the excess space to cell 0, 1 (the cell containing the component labelled "30")? I tried posting an image of what I want to accomplish but the system  disallowed that. Hopefully, my verbal explanation is clear enough.

```
package test1;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Main extends JTabbedPane {

public Main() {
    addTab("One",   createPanel1());
    addTab("Two",   createPanel2());

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test MigLayout");
    Main main = new Main();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(main);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBounds(200, 200, 800, 500);
        }
    });
}

private JPanel createPanel1() {
    JPanel      panel           = new JPanel(new MigLayout("hidemode 3, debug", "[r][l]"));
    JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("20", 20);
    JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("30", 30);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    panel.add(textField1);
    panel.add(textField2, "wrap");
    panel.add(button, "span 2, pushx");
    return (panel);
}
private JPanel createPanel2() {
    JPanel      panel           = new JPanel(new MigLayout("hidemode 3, debug", "[r][l]"));
    JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("20", 20);
    JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("30", 30);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    panel.add(textField1);
    panel.add(textField2, "pushx, wrap");
    panel.add(button, "span 2, pushx");
    return (panel);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was astonished that *any* cell was growing horizontally, because the default is not to. Until re-reading the doc for push:

> Makes the row and/or column that the component is residing in grow
>   with "weight". This can be used instead of having a "grow" keyword in
>   the column/row constraints

Using it in the spanning cell of the button effectively applies a grow constraint to the first column of the span. Without knowing your exact goal, it's hard to advise anything except saying: don't :-) One option might be to explicitly grow the second column:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("hidemode 3, debug, wrap 2", "[r][l, grow]"));
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("20", 20);
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("30", 30);
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
panel.add(textField1);
panel.add(textField2);
panel.add(button, "span");
```

As an aside: I always recommend to define constraints as high up in the hierarchy (layout > row/column > component) as possible - following DRY :-)

Comment: Thank you for the timely response. The "grow" in the column constraints will not work for me, but your comment got me thinking. So I took out "grow" and added "pushx" to textField2 and that has the same effect.